# Problem with MULTPLE SETTINGS File. Django/Python

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-settings, pythonpath, django-manage.py

I am trying to run a Django project on my windows machine. I am getting nomodulefounderror. The project consists of multiple settings files for prod, Development, and Test.
I am using a virtual environment, Python 2.7 and Django 1.10 versions
I need help to run this project on my local machine.

```
Python manage.py runserver --settings=settings_dev_sai
```

It throws me an error. Here is my error log

---

```
     python manage.py runserver --settings=bg.settings.settings_dev_sai
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 67, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "F:\brdge\bridge_sai\bridge\settings.py", line 38, in <module>
    from settings_dev_sai import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings_dev_sai'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 341, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 225, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 219, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 153, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "F:\brdge\bridge_sai\bridge\settings.py", line 38, in <module>
    from settings_dev_sai import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings_dev_sai'
```

---

---

**manage.py File**

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "bg.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

---

**Error log Updated**

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "F:\brdge\env1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "F:\brdge\env1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 316, in execute
        settings.INSTALLED_APPS
      File "F:\brdge\env1\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
        self._setup(name)
      File "F:\brdge\env1\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
        self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
      File "F:\brdge\env1\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
        mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
        __import__(name)
    ImportError: No module named settings_dev_sai
```

---

Answer (score 0):

i think that you just need run it

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=bridge.settings_dev_sai
```

because bridge.settings is a file not a package

Comment: Hi @Cauane. I tried running python manage.py runserver. It threw me `ImportError: no module named settings_dev_sai`. I don't know why I am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

It seems your project dir name is 'bg', so I think while importing modules you should do

```
from bg import settings_dev_sai
```

or

```
from bg.settings_dev_sai import *
```

also make sure `settings_dev_sai` is in same dir `'bg'`

Comment: Hi, @NitinGavai Thanks for responding to my question. I did try to add bg.settings_dev_sai in the settings file. but it threw me  **import error**. I have uploaded the error log. Please have look once and let me know what to do. sir

Comment: have you tried ```python manage.py runserver --settings=bg.settings_dev_sai``` ?

Comment: Yes, I did try to run with that server. but same error occurred

Answer (score 0):

I think i need to answer my question, The problem of nomodulefounderror, due to incomplete data in my Postgres database. I had dumped .sql file into the Postgres database which was given by my manager and later configured the settings file according to the database name and run command python manage.py runserver --settings=bg.settings_dev_sai. It worked perfectly.